# Retrieving TIMESTAMP from MySQL with Java comes at one hour before

Tags: java, mysql, database, time

Like it's on the title. Pretty simple but I have no idea where can be the issue. I am testing this on my personal computer so I'm guessing it could be because of my time configuration? Haven't test it on a live server I don't think it'll be different, it's the same code.

This is the value stored on the database as TIMESTAMP:

```
2020-06-01 00:00:00
```

This is the value I get retrieving it on Java:

```
2020-05-31 23:00:00.0
```

I've tried other timestamps but every single one it retrieves it comes one hour before the actual time.

The code used to retrieve the timestamp:

```
Timestamp dateToRetrieve = results.getTimestamp(DATE_TO_RETRIEVE);
```

Easiest solution would be to just forward one hour, but I'm not happy doing that. I don't think it'll be good in the long term.

Edit:

This only happens on one particular column of a table. I can't replicate this on any other table or even on another column of the same table. Every other works just like it's intended. I'm retrieving two timestamps from the same table and just one has this bug, how is this even possible? I've tried to change the order of columns, retrieve it by name or number and I still haven't got the timestamp as it supposed to but with a -1 hour offset.

Comment: timezone, can also be 6h30 so get teh time zone of the server and compoensate formthat with the time zone of the user, so all get the correct time independent from the point of the internet cnnection

Comment: I'm doing all of this on my personal PC. Client and server on the same timezone at the moment of testing @nbk

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your database is saving the date-time in `UTC` (which is a correct thing) and your Zone-Offset is `-1` hour from `UTC`. You can understand it from the following code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeString = "2020-06-01 00:00:00";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Date-time at UTC
        OffsetDateTime odtUTC = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUTC);

        // Date-time at UTC-1
        OffsetDateTime odtAtUTCMinusOneHour = odtUTC.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-1));
        System.out.println(odtAtUTCMinusOneHour);

        System.out.println(odtAtUTCMinusOneHour.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-01T00:00
2020-06-01T00:00Z
2020-05-31T23:00-01:00
2020-05-31 23:00:00
```

Comment: I'm at -4 UTC. Keep in mind I'm doing all of this (client and server testing) on my personal PC. What is weird is that when I save something to the database at the current hour it saves exactly at my timezone as it's supposed to. But when retrieving it, it comes at -1 hour

Comment: To increase the level of weirdness of this, this only happens on one table and only on that particular column. If I try to retrieve the date from another table it shows exactly like it is on the server, or even another date from the same column, it shows like it supposed to do, at the exact time. Only that column comes with -1 hour.